# use a javascript variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, qr-code

I've a problem with javascript :)
I've found this awesome code from https://github.com/andrastoth/WebCodeCamJS

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Simple initalization with default settings and build select menu</h3>
        <hr>
        <canvas></canvas>
        <hr>
        <select></select>
        <hr>
        <ul></ul>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/qrcodelib.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webcodecamjquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var arg = {
                resultFunction: function(result) {
                    $('body').append($('<li>' + result.format + ': ' + result.code + '</li>'));



                }
            };
            var decoder = $("canvas").WebCodeCamJQuery(arg).data().plugin_WebCodeCamJQuery;
            decoder.buildSelectMenu("select");
            decoder.play();
            /*  Without visible select menu
                decoder.buildSelectMenu(document.createElement('select'), 'environment|back').init(arg).play();
            */
            $('select').on('change', function(){
                decoder.stop().play();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would love to re-use this for a school project I'm working on with my friends, where we are trying to create a chat.
The only problem is that I don't know anything about Jquery an Javascript, I read through the code and I guess `result.code` is the variable that holds the information from the scanned qr. I've tried `window.location.replace($result.code);` , `$('body').append($(window.location.href = url + query));`, `window.location.replace('login.php?qr=' + result.code);` with no luck. I just wanted to transfer (post) that variable to a php page so I can use it to check inside the db if it exist or not.

Comment: If you want to know what `result.code` contains you could always use `console.log(result.code);` and then open your browsers console to see the results. Also if you want to build a chat I would highly recommend you learn the basics of javascript/jQuery if you intend to use it. Creating a chat application could be very difficult if you don't have a clear understand of the basics of the languages you intend to use.

Comment: Thank you very much NewToJS, I will learn javasccript for sure one day but for this project we are using c#. Our chat is connecting to a mysql db and I just thought, since i know php, to make a "viewer" but to handle the qr i need to be able to put it in a php variable . Thanks for the advice, I printed it out and that is exactly the variable I was looking for, is there a function that post to a php page to put in the loop (at least i think is a loop) resultFunction: function(result) {}? Thank you

Comment: If you want to send data to `php` and receive a response to further use on that page then you might find using `ajax` useful. A very simple example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: If I'm not wrong ajax is used if you don't want to refresh the page, but instead I want to redirect after reading the qr to a page and post the variable result.code to that page, something like login.php?qr=xxxxxxxx where xxxxxxxx is the value inside result.code

Comment: I've tried `resultFunction: function(result) {
                    $('body').append($('<li>' + result.format + ': ' + result.code + '</li>'));
                    window.location.replace('http://www.example.com')
                    window.location.assign('http://www.example.com')
                    window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'
                    document.location.href = '/path'
                    break;
                }` I've thought at leat one of them should be working :) I was worng, neither of them redirected me to the page example.com